# PHP cron job premature termination due to Maximum execution time fatal error

Tags: php, cron, fatal-error

I have a PHP cron job that is failing after running for 29 minutes. The error in the log (`/var/log/php_errors.log`) is:

```
[01-Mar-2012 00:32:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /path/file.php on line 2079
```

The crontab entry that triggers the cron is:

```
00 00 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/file.php
```

From my research I don't think this is related to the `max_execution_time` config setting because:

1. I know for a fact it ran for 29:18 mins (i.e much more than 60s like the error message).
2. From [the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) - When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.

**Q: Why is the script terminating early?**

---

Notes:

The script is very heavy, and does run many thousands of DB queries, but I was running `top` and the CPU load wasn't high.

The line from the error log is a `mysql_query` call:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM mytab WHERE mem = '$id' AND validto > '$now'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

---

```
> php -v
PHP 5.3.10 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2012 17:34:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.33, Copyright (c) 2007-2012, by SektionEins GmbH

> cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga)
```

---

*Update* - I found out why the script can run for 29 minutes of real time but PHP can exit quoting execution time much lower.

> Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running.

(from [the set_time_limit() docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#refsect1-function.set-time-limit-notes), but also mentioned in [the max-execution-time docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)). This was relevant for me because most of the script was long running db queries and payment API calls that won't have been clocking up execution time.

Comment: the cron job has nothing to do with your error, this a pure PHP issue. check for memory leaks, try to unset some of the bug arrays after executing loops. set free other big variables between queries.

Comment: You'll also notice in the documentation that it says: _the maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc_. Can you make sure that it is infact the PHP _CLI_ that is fired by cron?

Comment: I would also check that you have suitable indexes to speed up the select. Have you got a index on ***mem*** and ***validto***?

Comment: Thanks. I verified it is using the PHP CLI by triggering it from the CLI manually, got same error.
I do have indexes, the query is is quite fast (no mysql slow-log entries) but there is ALOT of these queries (e.g. 200,000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get `PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded` then for sure **some** piece of running PHP code runs statement `set_time_limit(60)` somewhere. PHP CLI mode may default to no timelimit but if **any** code path ever sets time limit, it will be honored. The reason that PHP did run for close to half an hour is because `set_time_limit` sets limit for CPU time and if the process is I/O limited or waiting for other processes, the total CPU usage would hit 60 second mark much later in real time clock.

Try searching all your source code for `set_time_limit`. If you don't find anything then add `set_time_limit(0)` at the start of the script to make sure that the 60 second limit does not come from locally modified configuration file. For example, on Ubuntu LTS the PHP CLI configuration is defined in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

Comment: THANKS. Useful info. grepping for `set_time_limit` revealed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can set a bigger value for time limit, or you can set it unlimited using [set-time-limit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

```
<?php set_time_limit(0); ?>
```

but acctually I use this too at the start of the script

```
ignore_user_abort(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately i can't write a comment, so my question here would be, what happens if you run this manually? Will it also time out?

If it does not time out when you run it manually, i would suggest that you call a little shell script, which actually runs a shell and runs "/usr/bin/php /path/file.php" within the shell.

00 00 * * * /usr/local/scripts/start_php_job.sh

```
File: /usr/local/scripts/start_php_job.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
date

/usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script

date
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried running it manually from the command line and got the same error as when it was triggered automatically via cron.

Comment: Can you record the Memory consumption during the run? What are your "resource limits (ulimit -a)? I would assume if it just stops like this, the buffer cache is full for the user max mem usage, the sql-server max mem usage or just the system ram reaches the maximum. I would suggest you do a ps -uef (i think this is the one which shows memory too) and grep your process, do this every 5 seconds. What also would be nice what the *return* code actually is. If you run it in a shellscript like described above you can get the error Code by echo $? and it will show up, maybe that gives you more hints.